# php - Data does not insert into table using checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

the checkbox is not working.. I could not insert new data into the table
there is nothing happen when I click the "add to cart" button.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item">
<ul class="thumbnails">
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product where pro_category='3' LIMIT 0,4 ");

while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)):
?>                                              
<li class="span3">
<div class="product-box">
<span class="sale_tag"></span>
<?php echo '<p><a href="product_det.php?id='.$data['code'].'"><img src="admin/pro_image/'.$data['image'].'" /></a></p>'; ?>
<?php echo '<a href="product_det.php?id='.$data['code'].'" class="title">'.$data['name_nl'].'</a>'; ?>
<br/>

<td><input class='minuman' type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='<?php echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?add='.$data['code'].'" class="category">
</a>'; ?>'></td>
<p class="price"><?php echo 'RM '.$data['price']; ?></p>
</div>
</li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>                                                      
</div>


<ul class="thumbnails" align="center">
<div id="single_product" align="center">

<?php echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?add='.$data['code'].'" class="category">Add to Cart</a>'; ?>

</div>
</ul>
```

this is my code for insert cart:

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $id = $_GET['add'];
    $qt = mysql_query("SELECT code, quantity FROM product WHERE code='$id'");
    while($qt_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qt)){
        if($qt_row['quantity'] != $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']] && $qt_row['quantity'] > 0){
            $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
            header("Location: keranjang.php");
        } else {
            echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Stok produk tidak mencukupi!"); document.location="index.php";</script>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is php-code which inserts into database?

Comment: [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions are deprecated. use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or PDO instead

Comment: @u_mulder  i already updated the question

Comment: Insert is done with `INSERT` query usually. here is `SELECT`. Are you sure what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

According to PHP Documentation, `mysql_query` is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0, and removed in PHP 7.0.0. [You may use `mysqli` or PDO instead](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

This row might cause problems, because it's not escaped:

```
<td><input class='minuman' type='checkbox' name='add[]' value='<?php echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?add='.$data['code'].'" class="category">
</a>'; ?>'></td>
```

and this is one of the ways to escape:

```
<td>
    <input class="minuman" type="checkbox" name="add[]" value="<?php echo '&lt;a class="btn btn-success" href="cart.php?add=' . $data['code'] . '" class="category"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;'; ?>" />
</td>
```

About "add to cart" - You can store the products in the session or in a cookie (I think cookies can be a better option), and then show them in the cart.